# Javascript for loop NESTED variable naming

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

Some older code for filtering I need to modify. Here is the original (3 shown here but repeats 20 times:

```
if(lot.sequenceMap.length > 1){
    lotdata[lot.instanceName].plan1 = lot.sequenceMap[1].planCode;
}
if(lot.sequenceMap.length > 2){
    lotdata[lot.instanceName].plan2 = lot.sequenceMap[2].planCode;
}
if(lot.sequenceMap.length > 3){
    lotdata[lot.instanceName].plan3 = lot.sequenceMap[3].planCode;
}
```

Obviously I want to use a for loop for this, but something with the syntax isn't allowing it:

```
for(count = 1; count < 20; count++){
    if(lot.sequenceMap.length > count){
        lotdata[lot.instanceName].window['plan'+count] = lot.sequenceMap[count].planCode;
    }
}
```

I've tried the `window['plan'+count]` but that doesn't work...any suggestions?

Comment: there is no reason for window... just plain old bracket notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! `.window` is invalid though:

```
for(count = 1; count < 20; count++){
    if(lot.sequenceMap.length > count){
        lotdata[lot.instanceName]['plan'+count] = lot.sequenceMap[count].planCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: beautiful, was able to make that syntax work in a variety of places, thank you!